# Converter data de tipo texto para tipo data

Tags: javascript, data

Preciso converter uma data inserida como texto (dd/mm/yyyy) com essa máscara para data e comparar com a data atual. Como posso converter? Estou começando a desenvolver e estou com dificuldades.

```
function VerificarData(dataRecebida){
  dataAtual = new Date(); // cria novo objeto com a data atual    
  //dataRecebida = new Date(dataRecebida);

  if(dataRecebida == '' || dataRecebida < dataAtual){
    window.alert("Digite uma data válida!");
  return true
 } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o `split` da data recebida para obter os valores de dia, mês e ano separados e com isso montar um novo objeto de `Date`:

```
if (dataRecebida == '') {
    window.alert("Digite uma data válida!");
    return false
}

const [dia, mes, ano] = dataRecebida.split("/")
const recebido = new Date(ano, mes, dia)
const atual = new Date()

if (recebido < atual) {
    window.alert("Digite uma data válida!");
    return false
}

return true
```

A sugestão acima é uma implementação muito ingenua e pode falhar a qualquer momento em que alguém passar uma data que não possua barras entre os valores, por exemplo, `01-01-2001`.
Trabalhar com datas nativamente em `JS` é um pouco chato e por esse motivo eu recomendaria você utilizar uma biblioteca terceira como, por exemplo, o [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Muito obrigada, ainda nao consegui resolver, mas conseguiu me dar um norte.